# What's wrong with my URLs in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo

I just joined a team to manage a asp.net 4 website with 1000+ pages of the url format

```
http://www.abcdefgh.com/ShowBooks.aspx?ID=1420
```

but it gets changed to

```
http://www.abcdefgh.com/(S(sdfdsf9835fgfdjgdfgderd55)X(1))/ShowBooks.aspx?ID=1420
```

or

```
http://www.abcdefgh.com/ShowBooks.aspx?ID=1420&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1420
```

This I suppose is happening from a couple of months and the traffic is heavy on this site. How can I prevent this url changing from happening? I want all URLs to be of this format only:

```
http://www.abcdefgh.com/ShowBooks.aspx?ID=1420
```

I have noticed three entries in my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/NoAccess.aspx" name="FORMAUTH"/>         
</authentication> 
<sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect"/>
<anonymousIdentification cookieless="AutoDetect" enabled="false"/>
```

What **disadvantage** will it have if I remove cookieless attribute from these URLs. WIll it break the earlier bookmarked URLs or **will Google/Bing SEO be affected** in any way?

Comment: AFAIK, cookielessness defaults to `AutoDetect` anyway, so these look superfluous to needs. As for your SEO problems, I suppose that anything changing the URLs will have some effect, though no idea of what magnitude - but surely the current URLs can't be helping SEO, either. And I'm not even sure why it's occurring in the first place - there is no re-writing going on, is there?

Comment: no rewriting..I think the url changes because of those web.config entries I posted

Comment: Are you in a web farm/web garden/load balanced environment?  If so, do you have your machine key explicitly in the web.config?

Answer (score 4):

Try this in your web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="15" />
```

to get rid of `AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport` in url

Comment: Will it affect SEO? I mean Google has cached pages with this url + a lot of people might have bookmarked the url as http://www.abcdefgh.com/ShowBooks.aspx?ID=1420&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=142

Comment: Thar's a good question. My guess is, AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=xx in the url will just get ignored. Just to make sure, you could try out a trivial application, deploy it on IIS and see what happens.

Comment: Can you quickly explain what did my previous entry do and how does your entry better it..also what about logins as I am using FormsAuthentication. Will it get affected? Sorry for the extra ques but I am just trying to gauge the impact that will occur as a result of the config change

Comment: No it won't affect SEO. It's easy to test by just making the change locally and looking at Fiddler to see if 200s, 301s, or 302s are returned.